# Price Or prices per unit?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Let's say, there're many units, which have different prices.

1. I don't know what the **price** per unit is.
2. I don't know what the **prices** per unit is.

Which is correct? & What are the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more idiomatic expression is "price per unit".  If there are multiple items all with different prices, then a native speaker would probably find a to express it using the singular "price".

> The store sells navy beans, black beans, white beans, pinto beans, mung beans, and both green and red lentils.  The **price per unit is different for each**, but they're all about $1/lb.

"Prices" is not wrong, it just sounds a little odd.

> The store sells various beans with different **prices per unit** for each variety.

However, there aren't many situations (outside of business-to-business transactions) where you would say "price per unit".  Ordinarily you'd just ask the *price*, even for items sold in bulk.

> A: **How much** are the kidney beans?
>   B: They're 90 cents per pound.

Comment: Does **"How much are the kidney beans?"** equal **"How much do the kidney beans cost?"**?

Comment: @hbtpoprock  Yes, they're two ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would match the number, singular or plural - the price per unit (each price) or the unit prices (all of them).